# Testing API's with RAML & Unit Tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, api-design, raml

I am trying to find a decent PHP solution to allow me to take a simple RAML file and allow me to test the API inconjuction with the RAML file and be able to create some unit tests.

I have tried to use this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/testing-apis-raml/) but i'm having issues, can anyone suggest how I can basically use RAML inconjunction with PHP Unit tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would be open to functional testing your API instead of unit testing it, I suggest you take a look at [RAML Tester Proxy](https://github.com/nidi3/raml-tester-proxy)

It is absolutely awesome and can be used with any server side tech and any client-side REST testing framework.